# Visual Studio 2019 : C# Deployment

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, visual-studio-2019

I am currently working on a desktop app using c#.  Once I have completed the application I would like to deploy it such that any users can automatically update their local copy, when I release new version.

Is this possible in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, look into _ClickOnce_.  It's built into VS

Comment: ClickOnce is not supported by .Net Core 3, so it's not the best choice for new code. I suggest looking into [Microsoft's latest installation tech, MSIX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/mt833462).

Comment: You can try ClickOnce. Please refer to this blog. [How-To: Use ClickOnce to deploy your Applications](https://weblogs.asp.net/shahar/how-to-use-clickonce-to-deploy-your-applications)